# custom simple constraint grails

Tags: grails, customization, constraints

I would like to create a custom simple constraint (like display and editable) which I can use within my Domain class. Is it possible to extend ConstrainedProperty class?

```
class City {
    String title
    BigDecimal latitude
    BigDecimal longitude
    Country country

    static constraints = {
        title       ( blank: false, customConstraint: true )  // filter can be also be applied as attributes: [customConstraint: true]
    }
}
```

Somebody familiar with this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create your own constraint:

- extend [`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.AbstractConstraint`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/AbstractConstraint.html)
- register the class as a constraint by calling [`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/ConstrainedProperty.html#registerNewConstraint%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Take a look at the [grails implementation of the size constraint](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/org/grails/validation/SizeConstraint.java) for an example.