# Create custom Validator

Tags: grails, validation

How should I create and configure a validator class to use it as a domain class constraint? For example:

```
class Link {
    String url
    static constraints = { url url:true }
}
```

**Motivation**: Grails UrlValidator does not allow underline character despite it being valid, see [rfc2396, section 2.3. Unreserved Characters](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

Comment: You could create a custom validator that extends their URL validator as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14734524/1264846

Comment: Thanks, James! Happy to learn how to create a custom constraint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a utility class in `src/groovy` with required validators (as static properties) and refer them in the concerned domain class.

```
//src/groovy
class MyValidators{
    static urlCheck = {url, obj ->
        //custom validation for url goes here.
    }
}

class Link {
    String url
    static constraints = { 
        url validator: MyValidators.urlCheck 
    }
}
```

If there is no need to externalize the validator to a separate utility class then you can directly use the validator in domain class as:

```
static constraints = {
    url validator: {value, obj -> ...} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks dmahapatro! I thougt there was a specific location for validators. Your answer and James' comment helped me to know better how it all works.