# Grails: How to mock a domain field validator?

Tags: grails, testing, mocking, grails-orm, spock

Is there some way to mock a domain field validator? 
Currently, my code in the domain class is looking like this:

```
isPrimary(validator: { Boolean value, Person obj ->
     .......
}
```

And I need to mock this function.

I tried to use it like:

```
Person.metaClass.static.isPrimary.validator = { Boolean value, Person obj ->
     .......
}
```

And it didn't work, any suggestions how to solve this issue ?

Comment: [Externalize the validator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19795708/2051952) in the same domain class and then mock it.

Comment: Can you please show me an example ?

Comment: Have to add example as an answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
class Person {
    Boolean isPrimary

    static constraints = {
        isPrimary validator: isPrimaryValidator

        //or this for a fully qualified validator
        //isPrimary validator: Person.isPrimaryValidator
    }

    static isPrimaryValidator = { Boolean value, Person obj ->
        //some validation
    }
}

//in Test
Person.metaClass.'static'.isPrimaryValidator = { Boolean value, Person obj ->
     //Do something else
}
```

Comment: Not working, I also tried: *Person.metaClass.'static'.isPrimary.Validator = { Boolean value, Person obj ->*
And it's not working also.